# Replace end of string with String/replace and re-pattern - Clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

I want to remove a substring at the end of a string containing some code.
I have a vector **a** containing the expression **"c=c+1"**
My goal is to remove the expression **"c=c+1;"** at the end of my expression.

I have used the *$* symbol indicating that the substring to replace must be at the end of my code.

Here is the code and the output :

```
project.core=> (def a [:LangFOR [:before_for "a=0; b="] [:init_var "c=a+1;"] [:loop_condition_expression "c-10;"] [:loop_var_step "c=c+1"] [:statements_OK "a=2*c;"] [:after_for " b+c;"]])
#'project.core/a
project.core=> (prn (str "REGEX debug : " (clojure.string/replace "b=0;c=a+1;a=2*c;c=c+1;c=c+1;a=2*c;c=c+1;" (re-pattern (str "# "(get-in a [4 1]) ";$")) "")))
"REGEX debug : b=0;c=a+1;a=2*c;c=c+1;c=c+1;a=2*c;c=c+1;"
nil
```

The expected output is :

```
"REGEX debug : b=0;c=a+1;a=2*c;c=c+1;c=c+1;a=2*c;"
```

How can I correct my (re-pattern) function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you're using to build the regex pattern has some characters in it that have special meaning in a regular expression. The `+` in `c+1` is interpreted as *one or more occurrences of `c` followed by `1`*. Java's `Pattern` class provides a function to escape/quote strings so they can be used literally in regex patterns. You could use it directly, or define a wrapper function:

```
(defn re-quote [s]
  (java.util.regex.Pattern/quote s))

(re-quote "c=c+1")
=> "\\Qc=c+1\\E"
```

This function simply wraps the input string in some special control characters `\Q` and `\E` to have the interpreter start and stop the quoting of the contents.

Now you can use that literal string to build a regex pattern:

```
(clojure.string/replace
  "b=0;c=a+1;a=2*c;c=c+1;c=c+1;a=2*c;c=c+1;"
  (re-pattern (str (re-quote "c=c+1;") "$"))
  "")
=> "b=0;c=a+1;a=2*c;c=c+1;c=c+1;a=2*c;"
```

I removed the leading `"# "` from the pattern in your example to make this work, because that doesn't appear in the input.